# Counter example for Joint Density function expression

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

For this expression:

$$\int_{x=-\infty}^{\infty}f(x,x)dx\leqslant 1$$

I know that the equal signs is the only thing that happens, not the less than sign. By using the condition to be joint density function:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x,y)dxdy=1$$

What is the counter example that we can have to prove this?

Comment: would you mind editing your question? in its current for it is confusing. What is $f(.,.)$? why the integral runs over $t$?

Comment: I just did, sorry about that

Comment: there is no counterexample for this. Simply the area under **any** density function, if there is no conditioning, is $1$. To see this you can link it to the probability $P(X<\infty,Y<\infty)$ which ia equal to $\int_{x,y\in\mathbb{R}} f(x,y)$

Answer (score 1):

Actually, $\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x,x)\mathrm dx$ can take any nonnegative value, $0$ included.

---

In particular, the inequality $\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x,x)\mathrm dx\leqslant1$ is not guaranteed.

In particular${}^2$, it may happen that $\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x,x)\mathrm dx=42$, or that $\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x,x)\mathrm dx=\frac1{42}$, or that $\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x,x)\mathrm dx$ is any other value in $[0,+\infty]$.

Comment: so the first expression isn't true, or is it true?

Comment: See addition (I thought this was obvious from what was already written).

Comment: sorry my last response was decapped, I was about to say should it be true if the expression falls in the range 0 <= integral <= 1. My point is i'm trying to find a range in which that expression falls into. Thanks

Comment: Here is your range: $[0,+\infty]$.

Comment: thank you so much, i will try to work on it based on your given help.

Answer (score 0):

Let $g$ be measurable and nonnegative with $g\left(x,y\right)=f\left(x,y\right)$
if $x\neq y$. Then like $f$ it is a density and it induces the same
distribution as $f$. We have quite some freedom when it concerns
its values on $\left\{ \left(x,x\right)\mid x\in\mathbb{R}^{2}\right\} $
and consequently $\int_{\infty}^{\infty}g\left(x,x\right)dx$ can
take all nonnegative values, as @did answered.